# How to add extra fields to serialized JSON of an entity

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm

I want to add extra field to JSON encoded entity. But this field will not be in the database. It is just a dummy field or a function. I have an entity like this;

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="sample_table")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class InstagramUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $userName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $fullName;

    ...

    private $extraField = "EXTRA_FIELD";

}
```

Normally, Symfony serialized this entity like this;

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "userName": "USER_NAME",
    "fullName": "FULL_NAME"
},...]
```

Question: I want to add this field to JSON data. How can I do this? I want to get a JSON like this;

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "userName": "USER_NAME",
    "fullName": "FULL_NAME",
    "extraField": "EXTRA_FIELD"
},...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using JMS. First of all, install JMS. You can find details in this URL: https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer

After that, modify the class like this;

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="sample_table")
 */
class UserTable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $userName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $fullName;

    ...

    /**
     * @VirtualProperty
     * @SerializedName("extraField")
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExtraField(){
        return "EXTRA_FIELD";
    }

}
```

Finally, return JSON with following method.

```
$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($user, 'json');

return new JsonResponse($jsonContent, 200, array(), true);
```

But I don't know how effective is this method.